# Cannot install subclipse on eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, equinox, helios

When I try to install Subclipse (latest version) on Eclipse Helios v3.6.2, I got the following error message:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1305107493878 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1305107493878)  Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1305107493878 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1305107493878) requires 'toolingorg.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64 [1.1.2.R36x_v20101222]' but it could not be found

Should I install equinox sdk?

I searched on the web on how to install equinox but did not found any tutorial. I found a Euinox p2 installer application  but it did not worked  (error message : internal error).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something is wrong with your Eclipse install.  I would guess there will be other plugins you cannot install.  I would try a clean install or a clean workspace and see if that makes a difference.  It seems like some basic core Eclipse pieces are missing from the install or the configuration is somehow corrupt.